# Django display a page title based on a variable stored in a view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I’m a bit stuck on how to display the titles for 2 pages that list articles of different categories using the same template. My article models have content, category (sport, politics, tech etc) and status. I want to display a page listing all sport articles and a page listing politics and I want to use the same template. I have tried storing the title as a variable in the view but this doesn't work

Views.py

```
 def sport_landing(request):
    page_title = 'Sport'
    cat_landing = Article.objects.filter(status='published', category='sport', published_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, "categorylanding.html", {'cat_landing': cat_landing}
```

Template

```
   {% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% load humanize %}
    {% block content %}
    <div class="row category-landing-title">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {% page_title %}
        </div>
    </div>
.
.
.
```

Is this even the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the variable to the context :

```
def sport_landing(request):
    page_title = 'Sport'
    cat_landing = Article.objects.filter(status='published', category='sport', published_date__lte=timezone.now()
        ).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, "categorylanding.html", {'cat_landing': cat_landing, 'page_title':page_title }
```

and use double braces `{` in the template (`{% %}` is used for template tags):

```
{{page_title}}
```

---

To answer about the whole pattern, you can avoid to repeat the code for each category by using a parameter inside the url pattern :

Add and adapt this line in the file urls.py, this will allow you to pass the category as a parameter to your view :

```
url(r'^category/(?P<category>\w+)', views.cat_landing) # i.e : mysite/category/sport
```

You need to declare a generic view like :

```
def cat_landing(request, category=None):
    if category:
        cat_landing = Article.objects.filter(status='published', category=category, 
                                             published_date__lte=timezone.now()
                                      ).order_by('-published_date')

        return render(request, "categorylanding.html", 
                      {'cat_landing': cat_landing, 'page_title':category.title() }
    else:
        return [...redirect to main menu... ]
```

Comment: unessecary space after `'page_title '` should be: 

`{'cat_landing': cat_landing, 'page_title':page_title }`

Comment: @DrumBongo i added an edit to answer the last question

Answer (score 1):

Pass title as context

```
def sport_landing(request):
    page_title = 'Sport'
    cat_landing=Article.objects.filter(tatus='published',category='sport',published_date__lte=timezone.now()
    ).order_by('-published_date')
    return render(request, "categorylanding.html", {'cat_landing': cat_landing,'page_title':page_title}



        {% extends 'base.html' %}
        {% load humanize %}
        {% block content %}
        <div class="row category-landing-title">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
        {{ page_title }}
        </div>
        </div>
```